# How to use object properties inside a parameterized function?

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, javascript-objects

I have been working on a dialog in a project and I made it into an object constructor.

```js
function createDialog(title, noClicked = function(){}, yesClicked = function(){}) {
  this.dialog = document.getElementsByClassName("dialog")[0];
  this.dialogTitle = this.dialog.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  this.No = this.dialog.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
  this.Yes = this.dialog.getElementsByTagName("button")[1];

  var dialog = document.getElementsByClassName("dialog")[0];
  this.dialogTitle.innerHTML = title;
  document.getElementsByClassName("dialogCon")[0].style.display = "flex";

  noClicked();

  yesClicked();
}
```

```html
<div class="dialogCon">
      <div class="dialog">
        <h1></h1>
        <button type="button">No</button>
        <button type="button">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is that when I want to access "this.no" or "this.yes" I keep getting **Cannot read property 'No' of undefined**. This happened when I used the below code:

```
var d = new createDialog("Sample dialog. Exit?", function() {
  console.log(d.No);
}, function() {
  console.log(d.Yes);
});
```

I need to use d.No to close the dialog. Is there any other way to do it? Or a fix at least.
I am aware of the fact that I could close the dialog from within the constructor itself, but I want to make it possible to do other stuff as well (like detecting whether user choose yes or no).


Thanks in advance

Comment: The issue is that you are calling `noClicked` and `yesClicked` inside the method.  That is prior to the point that the instance has been created and assigned back to `d`, so it will still be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling **noClicked()** and  **yesClicked()** immediately inside constructor. I think you would want to call them on click of **No** and **Yes**. You need to add these functions to event listeners of the buttons. Try below snippet.

```js
function createDialog(title, noClicked = function(){}, yesClicked = function(){}) {
  this.dialog = document.getElementsByClassName("dialog")[0];
  this.dialogTitle = this.dialog.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  this.No = this.dialog.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
  this.Yes = this.dialog.getElementsByTagName("button")[1];

  var dialog = document.getElementsByClassName("dialog")[0];
  this.dialogTitle.innerHTML = title;
  document.getElementsByClassName("dialogCon")[0].style.display = "flex";
  this.No.addEventListener('click',noClicked);
  this.Yes.addEventListener('click',yesClicked);
}
  

 var d = new createDialog("Sample dialog. Exit?", function() {
               console.log(d.No);
            }, function() {
               console.log(d.Yes);
           });
```

```html
<div class="dialogCon">
      <div class="dialog">
        <h1></h1>
        <button type="button">No</button>
        <button type="button">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue. It was a silly mistake tbh. I was thinking about adding the eventListeners after defining each dialog object (ig I should start taking more rests every now and then).

Answer (score 0):

As you have the constructor now, the callbacks are called immediately, and only after they have been called will the constructor return. Two remarks about that:

1. As the constructor has not yet returned at the time that the callbacks are called, the `d` variable has not yet received a value. So `d` in the callback will be `undefined`.
2. This is not realistic, as in practice you would only want to call *one* of the callbacks, and only when the user has clicked a button. At *that* time `d` would be defined.

You can still solve it, by passing an explicit reference to the constructed object. You could for instance pass it as `this` object:

Change:

```
noClicked();
```

...to:

```
noClicked.call(this);
```

And then in your callback, change:

```
console.log(d.No);
```

...to:

```
console.log(this.No);
```

Comment: I get it. At the time of passing it to the constructor, d wasn't even there and only exists after the constructor constructs the object (which is d). I managed to solve the issue in some other way, but I also appreciate your answer a lot (You taught me something that has bothered me for long. Thanks).